# How can I only match a leading space followed by a non numeric in Regex

Tags: regex

I need some assistance, I have been at this for hours now. I am not winning.

I need to match a space only if its followed by a non-numeric character (which I will replace with blank to remove it from the string).

I have tried this `^[^\s+]+\D` and it works to some extent.

if I have the string `" JLABCD-1 836397-BTD56517"` it return correctly without the leading space, which is what I want `"JLABCD-1 836397-BTD56517"`

if I have `" BefhMS JLZARL-1 836397-BTD56517"` it returns this `"JLZARL-1 836397-BTD56517"`

But if I don't have a space before the the first word, I want it to ignore all other spaces.

If I have `"_JLABCD-1 836397-BTD56517"`, I want to return `"JLABCD-1 836397-BTD56517"` or the original string as it is. Not `"836397-BTD56517"` which is what I am getting at the moment.

Is this possible with Regex?

Comment: Your title doesn’t mention anything about only matching spaces at the start, but all your examples and regex attempt both do. Please correct either title or examples. Is it that you just want to match any leading spaces?

Comment: If your regex engine has look behind, you can: (?<=^[ ]*)\D.*

Comment: Just curious, how does `JLABCD-1 836397-BTD56517` with the leading space return `JLABCD-1 836397-BTD56517` without the leading space using your pattern?

Comment: Meant to say If I have `"_JLABCD-1 836397-BTD56517"`, I want to return `"JLABCD-1 836397-BTD56517"` or return the whole string as it is. Not `"836397-BTD56517"`which gets returned

Answer (score 3):

Use a look ahead:

```
"^ +(?=\D)"
```

but it seems you just want to match any leading spaces. If so, just use:

```
"^ +"
```

---

The negated (due to its first character being `^`) character class `[^\s+]` in your regex matches anything *not* whitespace or a `+`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
^\s+(\D)
```

Replace with `$1`, it is a backreference to the capturing group `(\D)`. Or `\1` if `$1` does not work.

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/zKdWa6/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \D                       non-digits (all but 0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```